# Difference between sharded table and wildcard table in bigQuery.How to create a Sharded table in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Would someone be able to tell me the difference between wildcard table and sharded table in big query.
is the tables physical broken into different tables in shareded tables.How to query sharded table.Any Documentation for the same.

Comment: A simple Google search throws up all the info you should need. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables && https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

Comment: I have gone through this links before asking it here."Wildcard tables are useful when a dataset contains multiple, similarly named tables that have compatible schemas".Does this line means sharded table and wildcard tables are same in big query? I know sharded tables are horizontal partitioned tables and to query this we use wild card.some one please help me to confirm wildcard tables and sharded tables are same in bigquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a shared table is a table that is broken into many shards, typically with the same schema. You can use a wildcard to query across these shards in BigQuery.

For example, suppose you have man tables with the prefix `ga_sessions_`, you can select them all with `SELECT * FROM`ga_sessions_*`.

If you are creating these tables for the first time you may want to consider partitioning or clustering, both of which are often more performent than sharding. here's a link to the official documentation, which also describes some of these benefits:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Comment: Thanks @Ben p.Taking you comment as "Wildcard table and sharded table are same in big Query".Is there any specific way to create a sharded table?i tried making normal tables starting with some common prefix and it appeared as sharded table.Is it the right approach?

Comment: @user6639252 Yes that's right, just use a common naming convention and BigQuery is smart enough to group them together for you as sharded tables!